# PHP: Having a problem with get_post

Tags: php, forms

I am having a problem with the get_post method.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload2</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>  

<h1> Welcome to my search Engine </h1>

<?php

# SETUP
$thisFile = 'v4.php';

# INPUT FIELDS
echo <<< END
<form action="$thisFile" method="post">
<pre>
Search <input type="text" name="searchTerm"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Add Record"/>
</pre>
</form>
END;

# EXTRACT INPUTTED FIELDSA
if(isset($_POST['searchTerm'])) {

        # INITIALIZE INPUTTED VARIABLES
        $mySearchTerm = get_post('searchTerm'); # <- PROBLEM LINE!
        echo "You searched for: $mySearchTerm";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The code works well before a search term is entered.  The html looks as expected and this page is displayed in a browser:

[image]

After I enter a search term the pages looks the same BUT after going View -> Page Source I noticed something interesting.  The end of the page looks like this:

```
Search <input type="text" name="searchTerm"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Add Record"/>
</pre>
</form>
```

**NOTE:** There is no ending `</body></html>`

Comment: As far as I know, there's no get_post function in PHP. Is this a WordPress application?

Comment: Since I found my own trial answer should I vote to delete this post?

Comment: What is contained within the get_post() function? This is not standard PHP.

Comment: What is the answer for future people who find this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that get_post is not a PHP method.  My textbook defined it on the next page as:

```
function get_post($var){
  return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
```

Comment: Try adding the error display code I have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068855/php-having-a-problem-with-get-post/4068904#4068904 to see why that might be failing. Have you got a valid connection to the database at this point?

Comment: Glad you found your answer. You should make sure you have error reporting switched on in your PHP.ini during development; you would have spotted your problem straight away if you had that.

Comment: @Spudley: How can I do this?  Could you point me towards some documentation for this?

Comment: the PHP.ini file is in your PHP installation. You can edit it to set the configuration for PHP on your server. If you want to change it only for a particular site (eg the one you're working on), you can set the same values in the .htaccess file in the same folder as the site. See this: http://www.geeklog.net/faqman/index.php?op=view&t=53 and this: http://www.karakas-online.de/EN-Book/change-php-parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree with sixtyfootersdude. The only thing missing is the database connection.

```
function get_post($conn, $var){
     return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **MISSED** `include` or `require` for your `get_post` function and parser will push error with disabled error reporting.

And at the top of script add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('this_file_where_you_have_get_post.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can change:

```
$mySearchTerm = get_post('searchTerm'); # <- PROBLEM LINE!
```

To:

```
$mySearchTerm = $_POST['searchTerm'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no get_post() function in PHP perhaps you are calling an undefined function.

Add the following at the top of your PHP block

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

to see what it is going on.