# What is wrong with my code? Data is not deleted from database

Tags: php, database, delete-row

I've updated the code but keep getting new errors.
I'm really hoping that someone can help me and look at my code to see what is wrong. 
I have a database table on a webpage and I have one edit button and one delete button on each table row. At the moment I'm just trying to get the delete button to work and it will just not delete the row in the database even though I selected that ID. It looks like it's picking up the correct ID.

Can someone tell what is wrong? Below is the code...

```
<?php 

    require 'connect.inc.php';

    if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = get_post('id');
        $query = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id='.$id.' LIMIT 1";

        if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
            echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>".
            mysql_error() . "<br><br>";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM movies, categories WHERE movies.genre_id = categories.genre_id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed:" .mysql_error()) ;
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo '<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Release year</th><th>Genre</th><th>Director</th><th>Update</th><th>Delete</th></tr>';

    for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    //$id = $row[0];
    echo '<tr><td>' .$row[1] . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>' .$row[2] . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>' .$row[3] . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>' .$row[4] . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>'."<a href='edit_movie.php?edit=" . $row[0] . "'>Edit</a>".'</td>';
    echo '<td><form action="index.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'. $row[0] .'" /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" /></form>
                </td></tr>' ;
    }
    echo '</table>'; 

    include 'add_movie.php';

?>
```

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions. They are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use  [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: @peterm Hi! Thank you for your comment! I am aware but it´s a school assignment and we´re suppose to use this... I´m a beginner so haven´t read up on those other teqniques yet:(

Comment: where is your `get_post()` function defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just to be clear: 'mysql_query' and accompanying commands is deprecated and should really not be used.** The OP however stated that it was required for an assignment. The easiest way to replace them is to use 'mysqli_*' instead. For an example using parameter binding to avoid sql-injection:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Shouldn't it be:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
        ...
```

See this link for some info on 'get_post':
[PHP: Having a problem with get_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068855/php-having-a-problem-with-get-post)

The problem there was that the function 'get_post' was defined on the next page of the course literature, wich the asker hadn't noticed.

The variable $_POST['id'] contains the id-value sent from a form via an HTTP POST-request. You check if that value is set, and then you should assign it to '$id' like i wrote.

Comment: Oh maybe should I exchange the $id = get_post('id'); to that? The thing is I´m sitting with my book and not fully understanding everything I´m doing:(

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant. 'get_post' is not a standard php-function. See the link.

Comment: ve changed it but off course I got get another error. And I thought I was so close at solving this:(

Comment: Problem solved!!!:D Thank you for your help! It was a mix of a few wrong steps...

Comment: Glad i could be of assistance :)

Comment: @downvoter: Care to add a comment on what's wrong with my answer? The OP states that she is aware of that mysql_* is deprecated etc. I know you need to parameterize sql-queries. It's a question of one step at a time in this case i believe.

Answer (score 2):

**You forget to close action attribute.**

You have `echo '<td><form action="index.php method="POST">` change it to

```
echo '<td><form action="index.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn´t see that! However now I got this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\mymovielibrary\index.php on line 19

Comment: @Karolina i can't see get_post() in your page where its defined..?? make sure that function is included inside index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Your delete sql has wrong quotes

```
$query = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id='.$id.' LIMIT 1";
```

change to either

```
$query = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
```

or

```
$query = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the form action

```
'<td><form action="index.php" method="POST">
```

Also check your database connection is properly established

Perhaps this might help for get_post

[PHP: Having a problem with get_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068855/php-having-a-problem-with-get-post)

Comment: Thank you! I didn´t see I missed the " mark:( However I got a new error now:( just updated the question.

Comment: Please check the above link for get_post

Comment: Maybe I should take away that? I´m not really using get_post anywhere... Should I exchange to $id = $_POST['id']; ?

Comment: If you use `$id = $_POST['id'];` you will be using un-sanitized data in you sql, which you will be vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: @Sean But can I not now just adjust that with some SQL injection protection?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the `get_post()` function in the link that @GBRocks posted, you will see that `get_post()` was a shortcut function for [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: @Sean Aha then I´ll do that:) Thanks!