# php only updating first database entry regardless of what entry i try to update

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

So I'm doing a project for school, and I am trying to update certain items in column for certain rows in my database, however, regardless of what entry I try to update, only the first entry takes on the intended change.

Here is my update function:

```
if (isset($_POST['update']) && isset($_POST['serviceNum']))
{
    $progress = get_post($conn, 'progress');
    $serviceNum = get_post($conn, 'serviceNum');
    $query = "UPDATE classics SET progress='$progress' WHERE serviceNum='$serviceNum'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) echo "UPDATE failed: $query<br>" .
        $conn->error . "<br><br>";
}
```

And here is my update form:

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
                    <br>

   <select name="progress">
        <option value=" "> </option>
        <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
        <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="update" value="progress">
    <input type="hidden" name="serviceNum" value="$row[0]">

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="UPDATE">
    <br><br>
</form>
```

`$row[0]` is the row that holds the primary key which is serviceNum.  I have the form nested in a table, and when I run it on my localhost, and view source, it shows that each entry has the proper serviceNum for that row of data.  However, regardless of which entry I use the update button on, it only updates the first entry of the database table.

EDIT:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

    echo "<tr>";

    echo <<<_END
    <td>$row[0]</td>
    <td>$row[1]</td>
    <td>$row[2]</td>
    <td>$row[3]</td>
    <td>$row[4]</td>
    <td>

        <!-- Trigger Update Modal -->
        <center>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateModal"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
        </center>

        <!-- Update Modal -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="UpdateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog"role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Record</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-boday">
                        <center>
                        <form action="admin.php" method="post">
                            <br>

                            <select name="progress">
                                <option value=" "> </option>
                                <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                                <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                            </select>

                            <input type="hidden" name="update" value="yes">
                            <input type="hidden" name="serviceNum" value="$row[0]">

                            <br><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="UPDATE">
```

EDIT 2: MODAL

```
                            <center>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateModal">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                            </center>

                            <!-- Update Modal -->

                            <div class="modal fade" id="UpdateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Record</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-boday">
                                        <center>
                                            <form action="admin.php" method="post">
                                                <br>
                                                <select name="progress">
                                                    <option value=" "> </option>
                                                    <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                                                    <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                                                </select>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="update" value="status">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="ticketnum" value="$row[0]">
                                                <br><br>
                                                <input type="submit" value="UPDATE">
                                                <br><br>
                                            </form>
                                        </center>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- End Update Modal -->
```

Comment: Just curious, why the line `$serviceNum = get_post($conn, 'serviceNum');` instead of simply `$serviceNum = $_POST['serviceNum'];`?

Comment: This `get_post()` isn't a php builtin.  Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068855/php-having-a-problem-with-get-post

Comment: You have an answer below, take it up with them

Comment: @larsAnders I suspect `get_post` is something like `return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$name])`

Comment: Look in the Network tab of Developer Tools and see what post parameters it's sending when you submit the form.

Comment: @Barmar okay I checked the dev tools, the form data comes up as serviceNum: 10010 which is the serviceNum for the first entry on the table, even though I ran the submission on serviceNum 10022.

Comment: You're not using AJAX to submit the form, are you?

Comment: Can you show more of the HTML of the table?

Comment: @Barmar I have the jquery.js and the normal boostrap.js to run my animations

Comment: That's probably not relevant. Are you using AJAX?

Comment: @Barmar Then no, i am not using AJAX.

Comment: I suspect you have a problem in your HTML, and each row of the table isn't a separate form as you intended. That's why we need to see more of the HTML.

Comment: You can also use the `Elements` tab in DevTools to see if the forms are correctly nested in the table.

Comment: @Barmar

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
$result->data_seek($j);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

echo "<tr>";

echo <<<_END
<td>$row[0]</td>
<td>$row[1]</td>
<td>$row[2]</td>
<td>$row[3]</td>
<td>$row[4]</td>
<td>

<form action="admin.php" method="post">
<select name="progress">
  <option value=" "> </option>                     <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>             <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="yes">
<input type="hidden" name="serviceNum" value="$row[0]">

<input type="submit" value="UPDATE">

Comment: Don't try to put large code blocks in comments, edit the question.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, new to this, i edited the question

Comment: Is the form correctly nested in the table when you view it in the Elements tab?

Comment: What you've posted looks like it should work correctly, although you seem to have left out the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar Everything appear to line up in the elements tab. All that is below that section of code is a similar form that deletes the entry (which works perfectly), and the ending } to the for loop

Comment: Any chance you can provide a link to it?

Comment: Not a link to the code, a link to the site.

Comment: The problem is that no matter which Update button you click on, the modal that pops up is the one for the first row. So I think the problem is in the code that pops up the modal, it's not popping up the right thing.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but `class="modal-boday"` looks like a typo, I assume it should be `modal-body`.

Comment: @Barmar  opps, that didn't fix it though... Basically every time i hit the trigger, regardless of which row it's in,  it thinks it's the first row. So I might need to find a way to get it to open a different modal for each entry, which makes sense.  Also, updated the question to show modal code for the update modal.

Comment: @Barmar or `modal-booty`, who knows … ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same `id="update-modal"` in every row of the table. IDs are supposed to be unique, and looking up an ID always returns the first one. So `data-target="#update-modal"` always targets the modal on the first row, regardless of which one you click.

Add the item ID into the `update-modal` ID.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateModal{$row[0]}">
```

and

```
<div class="modal fade" id="UpdateModal{$row[0]}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help... This works perfectly.